# Detecting when the user chooses an option from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have a classic HTML select box:

```
Show:
<select name="show" id="showThreads">
   <option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
   <option value="new">Only unread</option>
</select>
```

Now, I need JavaScript to make an Ajax request when the user changes the selection in the box (without jQuery).
I have tried:

- Listening for clicks on the `<option>` tags, but it won't work for users using a keyboard or a touch device
- on an interval, looping though the `<option>` tags and checking if the selected one changes, but it seemed to trigger even when I simply hovered over the second option.

Is there a way of doing this that will work on all browsers/devices?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `"change"` event.

```
document.getElementById("showThreads").onchange = function() {

};
```

Comment: I seem to have encountered a problem... the onchange event seems to be rapid-firing! As soon as I load the page it fires. If I try to make the function alert something, it will pop up immediately, then keep repeating every time I press 'ok'! Why is this?

Comment: PS: the function calls itself to re-set the event listener once it has done its request, that's why it keep repeating. I still don't see why it fires immediately, though.

Comment: @Sean try this http://jsfiddle.net/A6Udp/1/ You were calling the function instead of assigning it to `.onchange`. I also removed the part that "Resets the event" because that made absotelutely no sense at all.

Comment: Ah! I see. that 'resets the event' part was a mistake... mixed up with previous expertiments but was obsolete... sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

Listen for `onChange` on the `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourAjaxCall(something) {

}

<select name="choice1" size="1" onchange="yourAjaxCall(this);">
    <option value="one">first</option>
    <option value="two">second</option>
    <option value="three">third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I do prefer to use Esailijia's approach, as I find it easyer to keep track of what is going on if I keep JS and HTML separate.